# Subsets of a disjoint union \ coproduct

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology

I have come into the situation where I have constructed a space $A\coprod B$ where the coproduct in this situation is a disjoint union. Is it a correct thing to say that $A \subset A\coprod B$ or do I have to do this via defining injections?
Many Thanks

Comment: It depends how (in)formal you want to be. We know there's a canonical inclusion $A \to A \amalg B$, which is a mono in very general cases (for instance, if there is _any_ map $B \to A$ then the inclusion is automatically a split mono). So formally, we should really think about this mono, but informally many people (myself included) think about $A$ as "living in" $A \amalg B$. This can _again_ be made precise with the notion of subobject, which has the same issues: Formally a subobject is an equivalence class of monos, but informally we think of it as one object "contained in" another.

Comment: So if I have an object $X:=A\coprod B$, after making this definition am I able to then say that X=$A\cup B$ as long as I think show that A and B are disjoint? I am doing this in the context of 'gluing' varietys if that helps.

Comment: Yes, for varieties it's entirely reasonable to think of $A \amalg B$ as being the disjoint union of $A$ and $B$.